# How to format exact with two digits after the decimal point in HTML

Tags: c#, html

I'm trying to format the results with fixed 2 digits after the decimal point. (:F2 in C#). I expect the results when I press the arrow to be 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ... 7.0, no 1, 2, 3, ..., 7. I would be very grateful if you could explain to me how this can be done.

```
<h1>Create Game</h1>

<section>
<div>
    <form asp-action="Create" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" />

        <label for="dlc">DLC</label>
        <input type="text" id="dlc" name="dlc" />

        <label for="price">Price</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" step="any" id="price" name="price" /> 

        <label for="platform">Platform</label>
        <select name="platform">
            <option id="platform" value="PC">PC</option>
            <option id="platform" value="Mac">Mac</option>
            <option id="platform" value="PlayStation 4">PlayStation 4</option>
            <option id="platform" value="PlayStation 3">PlayStation 3</option>
        </select>

        <button class="button" type="submit">Create</button>
        <button class="button cancel" type="button" onclick="location.href='/'">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[image]
[image: code]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`step`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_step.asp) HTML attribute.

```html
<input type="number" step="0.01" value="1.0">
```

Please note that this will only work with a decimal `step` value (it won't work for `1` or `1.0`).

---

If your `step` is an integer value, you can manipulate the input value with JavaScript:

```js
document.querySelector("#my-input").onchange = function(e) {
  this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
};
```

```html
<input id="my-input" type="number" step="1.0" value="1.0">
```

Comment: do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Inside your `script` section. Create a tag called `<script type="text/javascript">` inside your `<head>` tag and put the JavaScript code from the answer there. Also, change you HTML code to what the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoNumeric plugin to fixed 2 digits after the decimal point. After autoNumeric plugin is downloaded and added in html file, following code can be used (input type should be **text** type)

```
    <input type="text"  id="price" name="price" /> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoNumeric.js"></script>
    <script>  
        $('#price').autoNumeric("init", {
                aDec: ".",
                aSep: ",",
                mDec: "2",
                wEmpty: "zero",
                vMin: "0.00",
                vMax: "999999999999.99"
            });
    </script>
```

You can find detailed information of autoNumeric plugins in http://mozduljra.hu/szkriptek/autonumeric/ link.